# CSS overflow help needed - For jquery collpase

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, hidden

I'm using twitter bootstrap. It has collapse module.
I'm using it like this.

```
<a class="dropdown" style="float: right;" href="#collpasediv" data-toggle="collapse"> Collapse </a>
```

This is the collpasediv

```
<div id="collpasediv" class="collapse in"> 
<div class"circlecount">
1
</div>
<div class"content">
Some text goes here
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to move half of the circle of `circlecount` outside the collapsediv.
By default bootstrap applies `overflow:hidden` attribute for collapsediv.

I tried by applying `overflow:visible` for both collpasediv and circlecount. But collapse not working properly. Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks

PS: Circlecount div is just to display numbers with some circled background image. I want the half of the circle outside collpasediv and half of the circle inside collapsediv.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stylesheet for the twitter bootstrap there is the following declaration:

```
.collapse.in { height: auto; }
```

Add to it like this:

```
.collapse.in { height: auto; overflow: visible; }
```

Or overload it by adding a new declaration like this (leave the other declaration untouched in the bootstrap - this makes updating in the future easier):

```
.collapse.in { overflow: visible; }
```